# Making ellipsoids fall with the longest axis down

Tags: mechanical-engineering

Lets say I have a box full of ellipsoids. They vary in size and shape but are smaller than marbles. I want these ellipsoids to fall so that the longest axis points straight down.

Preferably, I also want to be able to control the other two axes, but that may be way too difficult.

I need an automated way to drop these ellipsoids in large quantities (a few dozen a second) with the longest axis pointing straight down. Preferably, there's something smart and simple, like the rifling of a barrel, that can work for this problem.

Comment: maybe have them roll down a pair of rails

Comment: @jsotola But, will that ensure that they fall with the longest axis pointed straight downwards?

Comment: Physics wants them to fall flat if they are have uniform density. If you put them in a pipe and blow them through with a viscous fluid like air, they will align longways with the flow in the pipe in order to minimize resistance. This is how potatoes are made into french fries with a water knife.

Comment: @PhilSweet given that potatoes are near ellipsoid, that's almost a full answer right there.